# C# Autocomplete Database issue

Tags: c#, autocomplete

I realize that there are plenty of things on this site for autocomplete but none have them have worked for me. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong. The current iteration of my code is as follows:

```
private void CustomerSearch_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.job_SheetTableAdapter.Fill(this.myDataSet.Job_Sheet);
    AutoComplete();
}
```

.

```
private void AutoComplete()
{
    myDataSet ds = new myDataSet();
    this.txtName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    this.txtName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    AutoCompleteStringCollection data = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            data.Add(ds.Tables[1].Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());
        }

    this.nameToolStripTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = data;

}
```

I also tried a variation of one on this site that uses a DataTable, but I couldn't get that to work. The autocompletion works if I manually add records:

```
data.Add("first");
```

So I am positive the issue lies in with how my program is not accessing the database for this issue. I should also say that I am not using a hardcoded connection string, I am using what is built into the Dataset. The database is working, all of my records are showing in my datagridview.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `myDataSet ds = new myDataSet();` - Where do you ever add data to this data set?  I can't see how that `for` loop would have anything to loop over.  When you debug, is that the case?  Did you forget to actually query the database?

Comment: The data set has data added to it through the designer, table adapter. All other things that pull from the database are working.

Comment: So, to clarify, what *exactly* happens when you debug?  *Does* it have data?  Is the loop entered?  *Specifically* when is that object populated with data?  “The designer” can be anything, but all you’re calling is the object’s constructor.

Comment: The loop is not being entered. the dataset row count is 0.

Comment: Then the data is not being populated.  You need to get the data.  I don’t know what you’re doing in “the designer”, but you need to query the database to get data.

Comment: That may be handling things for the designer, but it doesn't appear to be handling things for the code you're using in the question.  Perhaps some other methods or events need to be triggered for this `myDataSet` object?  Because clearly just invoking its constructor doesn't populate it with data.  You can examine that object's code and see more specifically what it's doing.  Or you could just query the database here in the method you're showing.